# How to remove unused namespaces from xsd using xslt. Keeping schema reference namespaces entact

Tags: xslt

I have an xsd file such as :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:element xmlns:ns2="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/UnitTest/TestProcess-End.xsd" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/UnitTest/TestProcess-Map Data.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:pd="http://xmlns.tibco.com/bw/process/2003"
 xmlns:ns="http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/jms"
 name="group">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="root">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element ref="ns:root"/>
            <xsd:element ref="ns2:root"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This contains some un used namespaces, can any one explain how to achieve it with xslt:- 
the output desired is :- Please note the namespaces which are used for schema references should be entact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:element xmlns:ns2="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/UnitTest/TestProcess-End.xsd" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/UnitTest/TestProcess-Map Data.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="group">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="root">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element ref="ns:root"/>
            <xsd:element ref="ns2:root"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Can you use a schema-aware XSLT 2 or 3 processor so that you can import the schema for schemas to at least identify the attributes which can have values that are qualified names?

Comment: Also that posted snippet is not a complete schema and is not even a namespace well-formed XML snippet given that it uses the same prefix `xmlns:ns` twice on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exclude-result-prefixes` in xslt declaration

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, The xsd in example can contain lots of unused namespaces and references which we will not be aware of. I wanted a generic solution which can remove all unused namespaces and also not referred any where. Any thought on that.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do `<xsl:copy-of select="/" copy-namespaces="no"/>` which will copy the entire document, excluding any namespaces that aren't used in element or attribute names. However, it might remove namespaces that are used only in attribute content, for example `ref="ns2:root"`. Detecting those cases reliably is quite tricky, especially if they are used inside XPath expressions (e.g. in `xs:key` and `xs:keyref` constraints).

If you want to remove all "unused" namespaces except those in a `$retain` list, you could do something like (again XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()=$retain)]"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and you could perhaps initialize `$retain` to contain all strings in the stylesheet that match `[A-Za-z0-9]:`, minus the colon.